# How to ensure that image files from Sphinx Documentation are copied "Automatically" in LaTeX pdf

Tags: image, pdf, python-sphinx, pdflatex

In my Sphinx documentation project, I am using images like this:

```
.. image:: /_static/carousel_filling.png
   :width: 300px
   :height: 450px
   :scale: 100 %
   :alt: Image here
   :align: right
```

In the Sphinx HTML docs generated, the images are perfectly displayed in the html pages. However, when I generate pdf documents using `make latexpdf`, I am coming up with the following error:

```
'LaTeX Warning: File `{carousel_filling}.png' not found on input line ...'
```

I tried to find documentation related to outputting images however I came up only with this:

Excertps [from](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-latex_additional_files):

> **latex_additional_files** A list of file names, relative to the
> configuration directory, to copy to the build directory when building
> LaTeX output. This is useful to copy files that Sphinx doesn’t copy
> automatically, e.g. if they are referenced in custom LaTeX added in
> latex_elements. **Image files that are referenced in source files (e.g.
> via .. image::) are copied automatically.**

So as per this, the image files **should get automatically added to the output pdf file**. But this is not happening. In the pdf file where the image should be there only a *blank rectangle* can be seen.

**Interestingly**, I can see that the image file has been **copied** to the folder **_build/latex**, so it means that `pdflatex` is **able to access the image file!!**

### Question

**How do I correctly output the images included in my Sphinx documentation in generated pdf file?**

### Edit 1:

In the terminal I can see the following **warning**:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `{carousel_filling}.png' not found on input line 931.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `"""{carousel_filling}".png' not found: using dra
ft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.931 ...t=450\sphinxpxdimen]{{carousel_filling}.png}
                                                  
? 
[21]
```

### Edit 2:

In place of the image (where the rectangle outline has been output in pdf file) I can see this:

`"""{carousel_filling}".png`

Comment: Checking on the **log** it shows this error : `! Package pdftex.def Error: File ` `"""{carousel_filling}".png' not found: using draft setting.`

Answer (score -1):

Don't place your images under `_static`. It is a special-purpose folder, not for images. E.g. create `img/` at the level of your rst files, move image there, and `.. image:: img/my-image.png`.